Is there any way to get rid of OneDrive in the Windows Backup settings and backup to a local disk?
I am trying to make sense of the Windows native  backup app included with the system (not third-party. I did not install it). I want to store the backup file on a local USB disk, not OneDrive.
This seems to be configured in the folders dropdown  on the main window: The window that says "Let's Backup your PC".
However, the folders dropdown box only says:

"You are signed out of OneDrive so folders can't be shown."

I have nothing to do with OneDrive I have never used it and don't want to.
So is there any way to get rid of OneDrive in the Windows Backup settings and backup to a local disk?

@Giacomo1968 There is a difference between two my questions: in one,  all options in the Backup's main window are greyed out. In the other, the options are enabled, but the Folders one  opens ok and  says I am not signed in to OneDrive so it is not willing to show anything.  Why the hell  to be able  to choose a local drive as the destination should I sign in to OneDrive.
